# Кнопка закрыть в табах Tab Control WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi, tab

Здравствуйте! Как можно добавить кнопку Закрыть в каждый таб (например как у вкладок в браузерах)

Tab Control создаю так:

`CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_TABCONTROL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | TCS_BUTTONS | TCS_FLATBUTTONS,0, 0, WIDTH, 83, hwnd, (HMENU)TABMENU, hInst, NULL);`

Сами вкладки так:

```
TCITEM tie;
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
tie.iImage = -1;
tie.pszText = tabTitleTmp;

swprintf_s(tabTitleTmp, L"New Tab %d", (tabs+1));
SendMessage(tabhwnd, TCM_INSERTITEM, tabs, LPARAM(&tie));
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать стиль `TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` и отрабатывать сообщение `WM_DRAWITEM` и `WM_MEASUREITEM`, но при этом вы получите табы в стиле windows 95 одинакового размера.

Если вы хотите, чтобы контрол выглядел прилично, вам придется отрисовывать контрол с нуля, рассмотрев 2 варианта:

- отрисовка с нуля средствами GDI
- отрисовка с помощью Theme API (DrawThemeBackground и т.д.)